# Installed Ubuntu 13.04 but automatically loads Windows, doesn't let me choose

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.04, windows

I installed Ubuntu without a problem, but when I turn on the computer it automatically loads Windows without asking which one I want to load. I have an Acer Aspire V5-531 running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the wubi installer file into windows.
Don't run the installer. However,You should get two options now during the boot.
Tell me if this works.
P.S.  This is only a temporary fix.
Good luck

Comment: It didn't work. I tried F12, F8 and those things but they don't work either, it just boots into Windows.

Comment: I installed Boot-Repair and now it works, thanks.